# Visio - placing a callout pointer at the junction between a shape and a line

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I'm trying to indicate a point in Visio with a callout; it's not the shape the line's leaving that's important, it's the actual point of departure. But whatever I do it keeps gluing it to the centre of the shape.

I've tried disabling Snap and Glue, as below, as well as changing the Glue To settings, and still it keeps snapping to the centre of the shape. Even the old standby of ALT-drag doesn't work.

[[image: [Gif showing snap behaviour even without Snap and Glue]

Any suggestions? How do I make it stick where I want it rather than where Visio, in its wisdom, thinks I want it?

Comment: Thanks, @Dave - I don't have the SU rep to put the pic inline yet. Much better now. :-)

Comment: Can you try and use a different type of Arrow?

Comment: For the time being I've just use Connectors; they do the job for this particular task, but I'm still curious how to set the Callout line connections for future reference.